# What exactly does acpi_backlight=vendor do

Tags: linux, usb, kernel, usb-3, acpi

I have an issue when booting Linux with a device plugged to USB 3.0. If there is anything plugged (USB stick, keyboard, …), the system hangs on start with blank screen and does not react even on SysRq. With USB 2.0, it works perfectly fine.

I had this issue in past time, but did not worry about it much. Now, I've found a solution – adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to kernel parameters. It does the job, but I wonder what does this parameter mean. I've Googled for that, but I've found only some advices to configure acpi_backlight, without any details what this means.

A link to documentation would be likely enough for me. Unfortunately, I can't find the documentation…